# Is there any way to change color after every 7 days after specific date?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change color of `div` after every 7 days. I have tried changing it using if statements but I want more specific way of doing it (automatically after 7 days add color).

This is what I tried:

```
     <div class="hello">
    checking

</div>
<script>
    var currentDate = new Date().getDate()
        console.log(currentDate)
        var hello = document.querySelector(".hello")
        function getMondays() {
            var d = new Date(),
                month = d.getMonth(),
                mondays = [];
            d.setDate(1);
            // Get the first Monday in the month
            while (d.getDay() !== 1) {
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
            }

            // Get all the other Mondays in the month
            while (d.getMonth() === month) {
              console.log(new Date(d.getTime()))
                mondays.push(new Date(d.getTime()));
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
            }
            console.log(mondays)

            if(mondays.length === 4 ){
                hello.setAttribute("alt","")
                hello.removeAttribute("src")
                console.log("in 4")
              if(currentDate > 0 && currentDate < mondays[0].getDate()){
                  hello.style.backgroundColor = "orange"
                  hello.style.width = "50px"
                  hello.style.height = "28px"
              }
              if(currentDate >= mondays[0].getDate() && currentDate < mondays[1].getDate()  ){              
                  hello.style.backgroundColor = "green"
                  hello.style.width = "50px"
                  hello.style.height = "28px"
              }
              if(currentDate >= mondays[1].getDate() && currentDate < mondays[2].getDate()  ){              
                  hello.style.backgroundColor = "purple"
                  hello.style.width = "50px"
                  hello.style.height = "28px"
              }
              if(currentDate >= mondays[2].getDate() && currentDate < mondays[3].getDate()  ){              
                  hello.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
                  hello.style.width = "50px"
                  hello.style.height = "28px"
              }
              if(currentDate >= mondays[3].getDate() && currentDate <= 31  ){              
                  hello.style.backgroundColor = "orange"
                  hello.style.width = "50px"
                  hello.style.height = "28px"
              }
            }
            if(mondays.length === 5 ){
              console.log("in 5")
              if(currentDate > 0 && currentDate < mondays[0].getDate()){
                  hello.style.backgroundColor = "orange"
                  hello.style.width = "50px"
                  hello.style.height = "28px"
              }
              if(currentDate >= mondays[0].getDate() && currentDate < mondays[1].getDate()  ){              
                  hello.style.backgroundColor = "green"
                  hello.style.width = "50px"
                  hello.style.height = "28px"
              }
              if(currentDate >= mondays[1].getDate() && currentDate < mondays[2].getDate()  ){              
                  hello.style.backgroundColor = "purple"
                  hello.style.width = "50px"
                  hello.style.height = "28px"
              }
              if(currentDate >= mondays[2].getDate() && currentDate < mondays[3].getDate()  ){              
                  hello.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
                  hello.style.width = "50px"
                  hello.style.height = "28px"
              }
              if(currentDate >= mondays[3].getDate() && currentDate < mondays[4].getDate()   ){              
                  hello.style.backgroundColor = "orange"
                  hello.style.width = "50px"
                  hello.style.height = "28px"
              }
              if(currentDate >= mondays[4].getDate() && currentDate <= 31  ){              
                  hello.style.backgroundColor = "green"
                  hello.style.width = "50px"
                  hello.style.height = "28px"
              }
            }
        }
        getMondays()
   </script>
```

in this code I am taking Mondays of the current month and adding color one by one. And I want to add 4 colors.

The issue is when we have 5 weeks: then it will not loop accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Something on these lines? I think it has bugs but it should give you a gist.

```
// Get a date
const date = new Date();
// Todays date ex: 30
const numDate = date.getDate();
// Todays day of week: sunday = 0;monday = 1; so on
const numDay = date.getDay();
// Go to sunday
date.setDate(numDate - numDay);

const weekNum = Math.floor(date.getDate() / 7);

const colors = ["Red", "blue", "green", "orange", "pink"]
const todaysColor = colors[weekNum]
```

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/kishin-karra/pen/yLYmYvE
Have updated the codepen as well

Comment: I think it could work. I find brilliant "going to sunday" (o to any _switching day_ one might prefer): that is an elegant way to align the last days of a week between two months (for example 1 Jun) to the corresponding color, without unexpected switches.

Comment: Glad you like it. I just like using javascript provided APIs and functions wherever possible.

Comment: it is not working actually , currently it is pink but after 7 days it is not changing to other color

Comment: brilliant sir .... i just need one last thing ... i dont need pink color, just need to loop with 4 colors ["Red", "blue", "green", "orange"] so for example today it is orange next week red and so on ... got my point ?

Comment: basically what your code is doing is the same thing what my code is doing exactly ....

Comment: just saw the comment. If I would have 4 colors, there might be a chance that I will end up with 2 weeks for the same color. else the data will have to be maintained. In that case, you might have to fetch the data from the server

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the current week number and use it for setting the color.

```js
const containerEl = document.getElementById('container');
const containerEl2 = document.getElementById('container2');
const containerEl3 = document.getElementById('container3');
const containerEl4 = document.getElementById('container4');
const weekClassPrefix = "week-"

// source https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-24.php
let isoWeekNumber = function(dt) {
  let tdt = new Date(dt.valueOf());
  let dayn = (dt.getDay() + 6) % 7;
  tdt.setDate(tdt.getDate() - dayn + 3);
  let firstThursday = tdt.valueOf();
  tdt.setMonth(0, 1);
  if (tdt.getDay() !== 4) {
    tdt.setMonth(0, 1 + ((4 - tdt.getDay()) + 7) % 7);
  }
  return 1 + Math.ceil((firstThursday - tdt) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1000));
}

let setBackgroundColor = function(date, element) {
  let weekNo = isoWeekNumber(date);
  // NOTE: I use % 4 to ensure it's between 0 and 3. If you want more variance colors, 
  // just set the number to the number of colors and add the classes to the css.
  // I recommend to put all styles in there as long as there is no real need to do it via js.
  element.classList.add(weekClassPrefix + (weekNo % 4));
  
  // For debugging only.
  element.innerHTML = date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
}

let setCurrentBackgroundColor = function() {
  setBackgroundColor(new Date(), containerEl);
}

setCurrentBackgroundColor();
setBackgroundColor(new Date("2020-05-31"), containerEl2);
setBackgroundColor(new Date("2020-06-01"), containerEl3);
setBackgroundColor(new Date("2020-06-08"), containerEl4);
```

```css
#container, #container2, #container3, #container4 {
  width: auto;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.week-0 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.week-1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.week-2 {
  background-color: purple;
}

.week-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>

<div id="container2">
</div>

<div id="container3">
</div>

<div id="container4">
</div>
```

Comment: sorry it is changing , is it possible to do it monday to monday ?

Comment: Check my example again. It should already be monday to monday, means every monday the color changes.

Comment: you are using 4 containers and giving 4 containers specific date , i want to change color every monday for the rest of the life (you can say)

Comment: Yes, that's what the example does. The specific dates are just for showing, that the code is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer for this. 
Your html:

```
<div class="block"></div>
```

Your css:

```
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

And the most important. Your javascript:

```
const block = document.querySelector(".block");
const dayInMs = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const delay = dayInMs * 7;
const colorSet = ["blue", "green", "red"];
let colorIndex = 0;

setTimeout(changeColor, delay);

function changeColor() {
  if (colorIndex === colorSet.length) {
    colorIndex = 0;
  }
  block.style["background-color"] = colorSet[colorIndex];
  colorIndex++;
  setTimeout(changeColor, delay);
}
```

Steps:
1.Get access to your DOM-element
2.Define a quantity of milliseconds in a days, since `setTimeout` works with milliseconds.
3.Define some color set in array or set, or another composite data-structure
4.Call a recursive timer, that every `delay` time will call `changeColor` function.

P.S. You can try `setInterval`, but recursive `setTimeout` is more reliable.

Here is codepen (you can change `delay` for another value, not to wait for 7 days :D):
https://codepen.io/evgeny-zubkov/pen/qBOeOxe?editors=1111

Comment: Javascript is client side based. That means it's running when the page is loaded. Usually people don't stay on a page for weeks without reloading. So this won't work out.